# Principal deserialization failure (MSP DMCCMSP is unknown) for identity

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I am getting following error while joining 4th Organization(dmcc) in our network.

```
# peer channel fetch 0 dmccdedch.block -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c $CHANNEL_NAME --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA
2019-02-28 06:00:42.099 UTC [channelCmd] InitCmdFactory -> INFO 001 Endorser and orderer connections initialized
Error: can't read the block: &{FORBIDDEN}


NOTE: I have created new channel called dmccdedch and trying to keep 2 organization(org1 and dmcc) only to be part of this channel.


**********Logs of orderer are following*************

2019-02-28 06:27:47.607 UTC [fsblkstorage] waitForBlock -> DEBU 27e Going to wait for newer blocks. maxAvailaBlockNumber=[4834], waitForBlockNum=[4835]
2019-02-28 06:29:36.658 UTC [orderer/common/server] Deliver -> DEBU 27f Starting new Deliver handler
2019-02-28 06:29:36.658 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 280 Starting new deliver loop for 185.78.160.127:43676
2019-02-28 06:29:36.658 UTC [common/deliver] Handle -> DEBU 281 Attempting to read seek info message from 185.78.160.127:43676
2019-02-28 06:29:36.660 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 282 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Readers ==
2019-02-28 06:29:36.660 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 283 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2019-02-28 06:29:36.660 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 284 == Evaluating *policies.implicitMetaPolicy Policy /Channel/Application/Readers ==
2019-02-28 06:29:36.660 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 285 This is an implicit meta policy, it will trigger other policy evaluations, whose failures may be benign
2019-02-28 06:29:36.660 UTC [policies] Evaluate -> DEBU 286 == Evaluating *cauthdsl.policy Policy /Channel/Application/Org1MSP/Readers ==
2019-02-28 06:29:36.660 UTC [cauthdsl] deduplicate -> ERRO 287 Principal deserialization failure (MSP DMCCMSP is unknown) for identity 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
```

#### Architecture

- org1 and org2 peer - server1
- org3 - server2
- org4(dmcc) - server3
- orderer - server4

Comment: were you able to fix this issue?

Comment: Yes.. I came to know about root cause when I converted the channel configuration of new channel into readable format(using configtxlator)  and realized that entry of 2nd Org(DMCCMSP) is not there properly.  Actually channel configuration was not updated properly  While adding the 2nd org in new channel using following link. https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/channel_update_tutorial.html....  following command was not executed properly.  "peer channel update -f org3_update_in_envelope.pb -c $CHANNEL_NAME -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA" .....

Comment: Consider
1) using proper formatting in the question description
2) posting an answer to your own question so that others with your same issue can benefit